# sort by values in dictionary when it is a date

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting, dictionary, input

I am a newbie on python and have encountered a problem when I am practising.
User will first input the number of people. Then he/she will enter name then birthday.

For example, if the use first enter `3`, then enter `John` then `1/1`
3 means that the user will enter 3 people's birthday and Name and date(format:day/month)
Then I am asked to sort their date of birth in ascending order.

For instance, if the inputs are `3` `John` `12/6` `Betty` `1/5` `Mike` `16/1`
it will output

```
Mike 16/1
Betty 1/5
John 12/6
```

Here is what I had on my hand and I can only think of zipping two list to a dictionary. Then I don't know how to proceed to next step.

```
number = int(input())
a=[]
b=[]
for i in range(number):
    m = input()
    a.append(m)
    n = input()
    b.append(n)        

dictionary = dict(zip(a,b))

print(dictionary)
```

Comment: Consider using the `datetime` module to handle date sorting

Comment: Are you on python 2.7 or 3.x?  Your tags are meaningless.

Comment: what is the expected output? dictionaries aren't sorted

Comment: You should use a list and not a dictionnary, as there is no order in a dictionnary. Then consider using a lambda function in the "key" keyword of the list.sort()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `sorted` with a custom function, followed by a `for` loop:

```
def sort_key(x):
    return list(map(int, x[1].split('/')))[::-1]

res = sorted(dictionary.items(), key=sort_key)

for name, date in res:
    print(name, date)

Mike 16/1
Betty 1/5
John 12/6
```

The critical bit is the `sort_key` function, which splits by `'/'`, converts strings to integers, and reverses the list so month has priority over day.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you store the dates as `datetime` variables, maybe like this:

```
number = int(input())
people_list = []
for _ in range(number):
    name = input()
    day, month = input().split('/')
    year = 2018  # a default year same for all if you won't prompt for the correct year

    people_list.append({
        'name': name,
        'birthday': datetime.date(year, month, day),
    })

people_list = list(sorted(
    people_list,
    key=lambda x: x['birthday']))
```

Then you can sort the list using `sorted()` and select to sort by `birthday`.

Answer (score 0):

We can store the names and birthdays in tuples. Then, in order to sort them, we convert the date to a `datetime.date` in year 2000. It's a leap year, so the 29th of February will be valid!

```
from datetime import date

number = int(input("Number of birthdays:"))
bdays = []

for i in range(number):
    name = input("Enter name:")
    birthday = input("Birthday:")
    bdays.append((name, birthday))        


def birthday_as_date(birthday):
    "birthday is a string day/month. Returns this date in year 2000"
    day, month = map(int, birthday.split('/'))
    return date(2000, month, day)  # 2000 is a leap year, so 29/02 is allowed!

bdays.sort(key = lambda bday: birthday_as_date(bday[1]))


print(bdays)
```

Sample run:

```
# Number of birthdays:3
# Enter name:Mike
# Birthday:29/2
# Enter name:John
# Birthday:4/5
# Enter name:Homer
# Birthday:2/1
# [('Homer', '2/1'), ('Mike', '29/2'), ('John', '4/5')]
```